# jQuery height sometimes working others not

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hi guys I have a jQuery problem I am stuck with. Sometimes it is working and gives my the right height and others a totally different height. Maybe it has something to do with the order that is loading or maybe I just did something wrong. Could you please take a look and let me know if you see a mistake there or what you would make different? I would appreciate it. It is in a Wordpress Site and it's in the header....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

// boxen gleiche hoehe

    if($(window).width() >= 1600)  {
        $(".home #fb").height($("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true) - 45) +'px';
        }


    $(".home #twitter, .page-template-homeLayout-php #twitter").height($("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true));
 });

 $(window).resize(function() {

        if($(window).width() >= 1600)  {
        $(".page-id-1235 #fb").height($("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true) - 45) +'px';
        }

        $(".home #twitter, .page-template-homeLayout-php #twitter").height($("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true));


});


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this issue is a result of bad code inside of your if statement which would explain the seemingly random occurrence of this issue.

This is inaccurate:

```
if($(window).width() >= 1600)  {
 $(".home #fb").height( $("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true) - 45) +'px';
}
```

It should be this:

```
if($(window).width() >= 1600)  {
 $("#fb").height( 
  $("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + 
  $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true) - 45
 );
}
```

Note that there is only one id per page allowed, so just using the id will be enough for the selector. And also, `height()` takes an int value and does not require `'px'` like a css property.

Same goes for

```
if($(window).width() >= 1600)  {
 $(".page-id-1235 #fb").height($("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true) - 45) +'px';
}
```

which should be

```
if($(window).width() >= 1600)  {
 $("#fb").height(
  $("#homebox").innerHeight(true) + 
  $("#homebox2").innerHeight(true) - 45);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using $(window) as the basis for your width. Instead put your site into a container

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In your JS then switch $(window) with $(.container) plus the edit from TravisJ